# How to return IEnumerable<T> as null

Tags: c#, automapper, azure-cosmosdb

I am having the below `ActivitiesDB.cs` which is a DBEntity class.

```
public class ActivitiesDB
{
public IEnumerable<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
public Guid ActivityId { get ;set; }
public DateTime ActivityDateTime { get; set; }
public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<MetaData> MetaData { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

sample data in DB(I am using CosmosDb in backend):

```
"Activities": [
            {
                "ActivityId": "4f436d11-7a61-4e7f-b0fb-0f0d5bb6be76",
                "ActivityDateTime": "2021-04-30T09:35:35.32Z",
                "UpdatedDateTime": "2021-05-03T07:45:21.5115588Z",
                "Metadata": [
                    {
                        "Name": "name",
                        "Value": "value"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ActivityId": "659e62c5-4408-42b4-8719-b8c577221d22",
                "ActivityDateTime": "2021-04-30T09:35:35.32Z",
                "UpdatedDateTime": "2021-05-03T07:45:21.5115588Z",
                "Metadata": null
            }
        ]
```

To display the data, I am having class `DisplayActivtiesResponse.cs` below:

```
public class DisplayActivtiesResponse
{
public IEnumerable<DisplayActivity> DisplayActivties{ get; set; }
}

public class DisplayActivity
{
public Guid ActivityId { get ;set; }
public DateTime ActivityDateTime { get; set; }
public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<MetaData> MetaData { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the code to fetch the data from DB:

```
 public async Task<DisplayActivtiesResponse> DisplayActivityAsync(Guid activityId)
        {
            var feedIterator = this.cosmosReviewRequestContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<ActivitiesDB>()
                .Where(q => q.Activities.Where(x => x.ActivityId == activityId)
                .ToFeedIterator();
            var requestModel = new ActivitiesDB();
            while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var items = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                requestModel = items.FirstOrDefault();
            }

            return new DisplayActivtiesResponse
            {
                DisplayActivties = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DisplayActivity>>(requestModel);
            };
        }
```

MappingProfile.cs:

```
 public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            this.CreateMap<Activity, DisplayActivity>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
```

Now, When I am fetching the data from db, I observed that if the metadata is null, I am getting empty array `[]` instead of `null`. I still dont know what i am missing from my end. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Why are you returning only the first result when you are getting more than one response.  You want to return items (more than one) and your code needs an IF to test if items = null and then return null.

Comment: @jdweng, since the query is based on ```activityId``` and anyways it will have only result since it is unique, I am returning the first result.

Comment: `ProjectTo` fits better here.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Can you pls elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `AllowNullCollections` to `true` when initializing:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
});
```

or directly in the mapper configuration:

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
}
```